# Magento modules disabled on their own

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I have a Magento system which is almost ready to deploy; but for some reason last night several of the modules went from true to false. When I go to **`system>config>advanced`** they are set to enable but when I open **`app/etc/modules`** and check the xml files several are set to false.

eg

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mage_Api>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Core />
        </depends>
    </Mage_Api>
</modules>
```

Can anyone suggest likely scenario or what to do now.

Edit: also three of the files, Mage_Backup.xml Mage_Admin.xml and Mage_Adminhtml.xml were blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* way that this can happen is by someone or some remote process (ftp, rsync, etc) manipulating these files by hand. Change access keys, change passwords, and review logs.

The GUI at System > Configuration > Advanced ***does not*** disable modules - it disables their output, as titled. There is NO connection between the `modules/[Module_Handle]/active` value and the value which is displayed in DMO.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed both admin passwords and the ftp password. I checked var/log/system.log ... lots of "Trying to get property of non-object" errors ... will try to check what that implies. What do you mean by "access keys" and is there anything else I should lock down?

Comment: "ssh keys" - just make sure no one and no app can hop on your server.

Comment: thanks - sorry I never had much to do with SSH keys, I always got the Hosting company to set them up, would I go back to them to get them to change it or how does that work usually?

Comment: If you are asking the question, there's likely no need to worry :-)

Comment: Thanks, yes I was talking to my host provider and SSH is not on that particular account.